# submit form automatically only once

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have made a form which I need to self submit automatically when page is opened.
I have tried this javascript code but what it does it creates a loop where form is submitted unlimited time without stop. I need the code where form would be submitted only once when page is opened. Please give me an advice.

```
<form id="form" action="form.php" method="POST" >
  <select id="main" name="main">
    <option value="1" <?php if (@$_POST['main']=='1') {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>One</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if (@$_POST['main']=='2') {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Two</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script>
  document.getElementById("form").submit();
</script>
```

Comment: use cookies to store a value and check it next time

Comment: After sending post for form, U are sending this again during loading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the form was previously submitted with the POST superglobal

```
<form id="form" action="form.php" method="POST" >
  <select id="main" name="main">
    <option value="1" <?php if (@$_POST['main']=='1') {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>One</option>
    <option value="2" <?php if (@$_POST['main']=='2') {echo "selected='selected'"; } ?>>Two</option>
  </select>
</form>

<?php
    if ( ! isset($_POST['main']) ) { // not submitted yet
?>
   <script>
      document.getElementById("form").submit();
   </script>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: First time the page loads `$_POST['main']` is not set, so it self-submits the form, which reloads the page, but then `$_POST['main']` will be set so it wont loop forever, like the other answers will, which was the question. Using an onload handler makes absolutely no difference for this.

Answer (score 1):

try calling on onload of document:

```
function submitForm()
{
   document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
window.onload=submitForm;
```

Since page onload called only once when page is completely loaded so it will call it once. Until you are reloading page again by code or using refresh of browser.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the java script for submit form automatically
you have to import jquery.min.js from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

after reading a td value of class error

```
$("td.error").each(function () {
    // 'this' is now the raw td DOM element
    var txt = $(this).html();
    n=txt.length;   
});
if(n!=0)
    {
        alert(n)
    }
    if(n==0)
    {

        document.forms["login"].submit();
    }
```

my html file contain code like

```
<td colspan="2" class="error"><br/><i18n:text><xsl:value-of select="$message"/></i18n:text></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```
<body onload =  "if (location.search.length < 1){ document.getElementById('form').submit()}">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try `onload event in body tag`..

like `<body onload="submitForm();">`

and your function like

```
<script>
function submitForm()
{
   document.getElementById("form").submit();
}
</script>
```