# How to resolve infinite loop caused by onLoadSubmit() of HTML form using Django for backend

Tags: html, django

I have a form that I want to submit dynamically once the page is loaded. one of the form field is preselected `post_city` loaded through an URL and preselected among many options. The Django template is as follow:

```
<body onload="onLoadSubmit()">
<form id="headerform" method="GET" action="{% url 'search' %}" data-action="" name="headerform" >
    <ul id="menu">
        <!-- city options -->
        <span>
            <li class="">
                <select id="post_city" form="headerform" class=""  name="h_qc" onchange ="this.submit()">
                    <option value="{{post_city}}"> 
                    {{post_city}} 
                    </option>
                    {% for city in all_p_cities %}
                    {% if city.city_name != post_city %}
                     <option value="{{city.city_name}}">
                     {{city.city_name}}
                     </option> 
                     {% endif %}
                     {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </li>
        </span>

         <!-- category options  -->
        <span>
            <li >
                <select id="catAbb" name="h_qcc">
                    <option value="{{category_name}}"> 
                    {{category_name}} 
                    </option>
                    {% for category in all_p_categories %}
                    {% if category.category_name != category_name %}
                     <option value="{{category.category_name}}">
                     {{category.category_name}}
                     </option> 
                     {% endif %}
                     {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </li>
        </span>
    </ul>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoadSubmit()
    {
        document.headerform.submit();
    }
</script>
</body>
```

This is working well except that it gets an infinite loop. That is  once the page is loaded, it keeps reloading for infinite that I could not even scroll down the page.

Note: I could simply add submit button. However, I want the form is submitted automatically once the page is loaded based on the preselected options passed through the URL from previous page.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many suggested solutions I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23005964/submit-form-automatically-only-once) made by [bakchod_launda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6482223/bakchod-launda) which worked for me.

```
<body onload =  "if (location.search.length < 1){ document.getElementById('form').submit()}">
```